# How do pass information from a browser into a Silverlight App when you create the App in html?

Tags: silverlight

When you create a Silverlight app using:

```
<asp:Silverlight id="SlApp" runat="server" Source="~/ClientBin/SLApp.xap" MinimumVersion="2.0" />
```

is there a way to pass in custom information (like a string) so that it can be accessed inside the Silverlight app's C# code?  Like inside the Silverlight's App() constructor?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the Silverlight ASP.NET web control, there is an 'InitParameters' property that you can use to pass in initialization parameters as key/value pairs...

```
<asp:Silverlight id="SlApp" runat="server" Source="~/ClientBin/SLApp.xap" MinimumVersion="2.0" InitParameters="id=12345,name=john" />
```

Then in your Silverlight application, you can read those properties in the application's Startup event...

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        Startup += Application_Startup;
    }

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = e.InitParams["id"];
        string name = e.InitParams["name"];
    }
}
```

The InitParameters property of the StartupEventArgs is simply a generic IDictionary<string,string>.